# chaining promises implementation gives already resolved error

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to chain the promises as follows,

```
 doAsyncWork(123)
   .then(function (result){
        return doAnotherAsync();})
   .then(function (result2){
         return displayText(result2)}

function doAsyncWork(value){
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                var time  = setTimeOut(function (){
                    resolve(value)}, Math.random * 1000);
                 });
      }

 function doAnotherAsyn(){
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                  var time = setTimeOut(function (){
                      resolve(456)}, Math.random * 100);
        });}
```

The Output is:

123

undefined

uncaught Error: promise is already been resolved

Promises object created in the above code is implemented as.

```
Promise = (function()
{/**
 * Promise Status Enumerator
 * @private
 */
var Status = {
    Pending: 0,
    Resolved: 1,
    Rejected: 2
};

var Promise = function (fn) {
    /**
     * @private
     * @type {Status}
     */
    this.status = Status.Pending;
    /**
     * @private
     * @type {object}
     */
    this.result = undefined;
    /**
     * @private
     * @type {object}
     */
    this.reason = undefined;
    /**
     * @private
     * @type {Array}
     */
    this.queue = [];

    if (typeof fn !== "function") {
        reject.call(this, new Error('invalid executor'));
    }

    try {//catch errors
        fn.call(null, resolve.bind(this), reject.bind(this));
    } catch (e) {
        reject.call(this, e);
    }
};


Promise.prototype = {
    /**
     * Appends fulfillment and rejection handlers to the promise and return
     * a new promise object
     */
    then: function (onResolved, onRejected) {
        if (this.status === Status.Resolved) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                resolve(isFunction(onResolved) ? onResolved.call(null, this.result) : undefined);
            }.bind(this));
        }

        if (this.status === Status.Rejected) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                reject(isFunction(onRejected) ? onRejected.call(null, this.reason) : undefined);
            }.bind(this));
        }

        if (this.status === Status.Pending) {
            //pending
            var instance = this;
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                //run resolve or reject object when parent's resolve or reject is called
                instance.queue.push({
                    resolve: function (result) {
                        resolve(isFunction(onResolved) ? onResolved.call(null, result) : undefined);
                    },
                    reject: function (reason) {
                        reject(isFunction(onRejected) ? onRejected.call(null, reason) : undefined);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    },

    /**
     * Appends a rejection handler callback to the promise and returns a new promise resolving to the return value
     * of the callback
     *
     * @param {?function(error)} onRejected called if the promise is rejected
     */
    catch: function (onRejected) {
        return this.then(undefined, onRejected);
    }
};
/**
 * internal resolve function,simply assigns the result to the promise object
 * @private
 * @param {object} result
 */
function resolve(result) {

    var self = this;
    if (self.status !== Status.Pending) {
        throw "The Promise has already been resolved.";
    }

    if(result instanceof  Promise){

        self.result = result.then(function(innerResult){
            resolve(innerResult).bind(self);
            self.status = Status.Pending;
        });
    }
    else{
        this.result = result;
        this.status = Status.Resolved;
    }

    //call the queued listeners
    this.queue
        .map(function (item) {
            return item.resolve;
        })
        .forEach(function queueResolver(resolver) {
            resolver.call(null, result);
        });

    //delete queue
    this.queue = [];
}
```

I have followed the promises A+ spec to write this.Please let me know if I have not addressed any specification.
Kindly help me understanding

1.how did the state of inner promise created (in doAnotherAsyn())change to resolve in my code, when it should be pending.

2.How do we differentiate outer and inner promise objects in chaining promises concept?

3.I have noticed that "result2" in the code above is a promise object which should be the resolved result of the inner promise been created within the function. How do I address these?

Comment: Where are you doing the outputs that you get your log from? What is `displayText`?

Comment: `self.result = result.then(function(innerResult){ resolve(innerResult).bind(self); …` makes no sense

Comment: Please fix syntax errors in your snippet first: `setTimeOut`, braces etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response georg and sure i will fix all syntax errors, coming to the self.result, if a function returns a promise we should internally resolve and return the result right? so i did it this way. can you please guide me in how to achieve that?

Comment: No, you cannot `return` results, you can only `resolve.call(self, innerResult)`

Comment: This worked Bergi thankyou so much!! i fixed it